# How to fix preview for Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I try to use Jetpack Compose in my existing project the problem is if I include `@Preview` annotation it doesn't show me anything, just this

[image]

There is my code

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun test() {
    Text(text = "HELLO")
}
```

What am I missing here?

**UPD**

I assume this issue somehow related to that fact that I added Compose to existing project, as if I try to create the project from the scratch it works perfectly.

In addition I would like to add the error screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Among adding these:

```kotlin
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.2.1"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.2.1"
```

Add these too:

```kotlin
debugImplementation "androidx.customview:customview:1.2.0-alpha01"
debugImplementation "androidx.customview:customview-poolingcontainer:1.0.0"
```

Worked for me with
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2,
AGP 7.2.2,
ComposeCompiler 1.3.1,
Compose 1.2.1

[Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227767363#comment2]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the following dependencies in your project

```
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.2.1"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.2.1"
```

Plus you are on the Android Gradle Plugin version that matches with the version of Android Studio you are using.

Comment: Added UPD in the question. And I double checked I have the related dependences in the gradle.

Comment: I have these dependencies and still have the same issue. `Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2`, `AGP 7.2.2`, `ComposeCompiler 1.3.1`, `Compose 1.2.1`, A fully compose project

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by replacing

```
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
```

With

```
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
```

It's not optimal since the library will be included in release builds but it works as a temporal fix.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the preview window had a very low scale. Pressing the plus button several times showed the composable elements with Preview annotation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).